# Query SPARQL resulting certain class

Tags: java, sparql, ontology, reasoning

i want to show the result from my query with just 1 or 2 class(es). this picture below is my current result:

[image]

there it can be seen that in column e there are several classes to be addressed. here I just want to bring up the "Information System" or "Sistem Informasi" class(es) only. Those classes are the direct subclass of Thing.

My query SPARQL shown in below:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT ?x ?e " +
                   "WHERE { ?x rdfs:label  ?a ;" +
                 "  rdfs:subClassOf ?b ." +
                 "OPTIONAL {"+
                 "  ?b rdfs:label ?e ."+
                    " }"+
                 "  ?b rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ."+
                 "  FILTER (regex(str(?a), '%s','i')) ." +
                   "}";
```

oh ya, i am using Jena for reasoning my ontology and the result keep showing their all classes. maybe the problem from there? so i can not choose the certain class? please advise me

Comment: `select ?x (sample(?e) as ?se) { ... } group by ?x`

Comment: also, I'm wondering, what is your query supposed to do?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. My current query, i supposed to, is to resulting the subclass of Thing. But i just want to show one certain class (from subclass of Thing). But i dont have any idea for it

Comment: of you want to have just one subclass of owl:Thing, why are you not doing `select  ?x where {?x rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing} limit 1` - what is wrong with this?

Comment: Umm, i haven't used `limit` yet. But, based on my question is more like i just wanna showing "sistem informasi" class. Can `limit` facilitate that?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're doing ,sorry. You have to learn to make a proper understandable question, with given data, expected output etc. - and you should relearn SPARQL or at least try to understand what your current query is doing. It's unclear what is given and what not. Last guess from my side: `select ?cls where {?cls rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ; rdfs:label ?clsLabel filter (regex(str(?clsLabel), 'sistem informasi','i'))}` - if that's not what yout want, you should say what the input is. Just picking a particular class from all subclasses of owl:Thing must be based on some condition

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulfaamnf/classification-semantics/master/ontologi_cs_fix.rdf this link refers to my full RDF file. you can check it. this RDF shows that so many subclasses under owl:Thing. if i input "semantik web", it should has result bunch of classes in column e (as I demonstrated in the picture). but, i just want it to resulting an "sistem informasi" class. sorry if i make you confused. i hope you can help me. thank you for the syntax you gave me before. i'll try it

Comment: ok, but based on which criteria should the query return just the single class "sistem informasi"? What exactly is the input?

Comment: Yes. Bcs "sistem informasi" is direct subclass of Thing. For the input, I put the example in my SPARQL above that i use `%s` which is string. Why i use that? Bcs i do query in looping but that's not a problem. Example like, i put the string "web semantik". So the query will result "bahasa deskripsi web semantik" bcs there's a class with name like that. That class also be a part of "sistem informasi" but it's look like at a certain depth. I just wanna find a way that "bahasa deskripsi web semantik" is "sistem informasi" in direct way